# Opening a Specific Web Browser With a specific URL JAVA

Tags: java

I've been using the Desktop -> browse() method so far to open the default browser with a URL i now want to move opening 3 different browsers: IE, Chrome, Firefox what would be the best solution to do this?

I was thinking just Inputting into the Cmd line

start (browser.exe) (URL) as that would work

Or is there a better solution?

Many thanks for any advice

Comment: yes, command line is the way to do it.